# Wrong Opportunity Stage Order in Report

Tags: reporting, opportunity, sort, stagename

[image]

A report I made is showing the wrong opportunity stage order. For example, "Complete" should be the final stage and it should be followed by "Arrival".

The order is correct in the Opportunity detail page in the StageName picklist field.

Sorting the Stage column in this particular report ascending or descending maintains this incorrect sort order.

What can I do?

Comment: Please check out this [dev forum](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8VyrSAF) discussion, if it gives you an idea to try something to reorder Stages and check its behaviour.

Comment: i tried playing around changing the stagename order but to no avail. This issue exists in our sandbox and we haven't gone live yet so hopefully it doesn't repeat on production. If so I'll have to contact support. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had opportunities with values for StageName that had been removed. Once I changed those opportunities' stagenames with up to date values, the problem was resolved.